# Можно ли сделать выборку родительского элемента по дочернему в css?

Tags: css, css3

Добрый день, подскажите, можно ли выбрать родителя при ховере или фокусе дочернего элемента без js.
Например, выборки могут быть по `nth-of-type :not ~` + и т.д. Допустим, у нас вложенность следующего типа:

```
<label>
    <input>
 </label>
```

Могу ли я как-то по событию фокус или ховер на `input` выбирать `label`?

Comment: нельзя. (7 символов нужно...:\ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `CSS` есть ограничение - к предкам обращаться нельзя. Никак.
Как и к предыдущим элементам.
Используйте `JS`.